Confusion about modular form as global sections
I read from quite a lot of places (say wikipedia and some lecture notes) that

Modular forms of weight $k$ are global sections of the $k$-th tensor power of the canonical bundle on the modular curve.

However, let's take the easiest example: $X(1)$ which simply $\mathbb P^1$. The canonical bundle is $\omega=\mathscr O(-2)$, and $\omega^{\otimes k}=\mathscr O(-2k)$. But they all have trivial global sections on $\mathbb P^1$?
Did I miss something?

I think you need to work with moduli stacks in general.

@LukasHeger Ah thanks. So, this is very first and "easiest" case $X(1)$ already in the "in general" case?

Yes. There are easier cases: if the level is high enough, then the moduli stack is represented by a scheme.

This example is discussed in Voight and Zureick-Brown's The canonical ring of a stacky curve. See sections 1.3, 6.2, and chapter 7.

The issue here is not stacks vs. schemes, as claimed in the comments; its is that the word "canonical" is being used in two incompatible ways.
It is true that on any modular curve (viewed as a stack), there is a line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ such that the sections of the $k$-th power of it are modular forms. Moreover, this line bundle is "canonical" in the sense that it is uniquely defined and invariant under many natural operations. However, it is not "the canonical bundle" in the sense of algebraic geometry (the bundle of regular differential forms); in fact the geometers' canonical bundle is closely related (but not quite the same as) $\mathcal{L}^{\otimes 2}$, not $\mathcal{L}$ itself.
See here for a previous question in which the same confusion occurs.

The relationship between the two different "canonical" bundles is given by the Kodaira-Spencer isomorphism, correct? Or are there even more nuances than that?

Kodaira-Spencer tells you that if $\Gamma$ is torsion-free (so no stackiness arises), then $\mathcal{L}^{\otimes 2} \cong \Omega_{X(\Gamma) / \mathbb{C}} (D)$, where $D$ is the divisor of cusps. But you mustn't forget the cusps there.
